# C# Get the phonemic spelling of a word using XSAMPA

Tags: dll, resources, speech, phonetics

Im searching for resources and ways to do this on the internet, but I just can find any links.

The only place I can find that can do this is [THIS LINK](http://theaccentlab.com/) where you can enter a word and it gives you the phonemic spelling of that word in *SAMPA*.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272932/quickest-array-initialization) posted something in the line of *xsampa*, but doesn't give any clue on how he went about getting those classes etc. Do you know if this is even possible in C#, and where I can find resources about this?

How your translation SHOULD look like to work with JULIUS.

Example:

```
abatement   @ b @i t m @ n t    1   0
abates  @ b @i t s  1   0
abating @ b @i t i N    1   0
abattoir    { b @ t w A: r\ 1   0
abattoirs   { b @ t w A: z  1   0
abbess  { b E s 1   0
abbesses    { b E s @ s 1   0
abbey   { b i   1   0
abbeys  { b i z 1   0
abbot   { b @ t 1   0
abbots  { b @ t s   1   0
abbreviate  @ b r\ i: v i @i t  1   0
abbreviated @ b r\ i: v i @i t @ d  1   0
abbreviates @ b r\ i: v i @i t s    1   0
abbreviating    @ b r\ i: v i @i t i N  1   0
abbreviation    @ b r\ i: v i @i S @ n  1   0
abbreviations   @ b r\ i: v i @i S @ n z    1   0
abdicate    { b d i k @i t  1   0
abdicated   { b d i k @i t @ d  1   0
abdicates   { b d i k @i t s    1   0
```

Should one first convert it to Sampa then replace the words to X-sampa compatible with Juluis, or Directly use some mapping to convert it to X-Sampa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a dictionary of English pronunciations. One commonly-used one is the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMU_Pronouncing_Dictionary)), which lists the pronunciations of 133746 words. It is freely available (public domain) as a plain-text file.

It uses [its own weird phonetic transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet), but it won't be difficult to replace each phoneme with the X-SAMPA equivalent, provided you don't care about lexical stress. Example:

> *stack overflow*
>   `S T AE K . OW V ER F L OW2 .`

can be converted to X-SAMPA

> `/st{k Owvr=flOw/`

using a lookup table for each phoneme.

The dictionary doesn't contain all English words, but [there is also a tool to guess the pronunciation of words not in the dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html).

Comment: That sounds like a plan, but where would i get the lookup table for X-sampa? And also, i need to replace some characters in the X-sampa converted words because the program i use (Julius) cant handle all the characters of X-sampa (and yet it uses X-sampa, don't ask me why..), so ill need to run them through 2 lookup tables..

Comment: @Ruan: I don't know of any pre-made table, but you can make one by cross-referencing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA, and using only characters that Julius understands.

Comment: The reason "Julius" uses X-SAMPA, but not all of it is that X-SAMPA is used to describe phonetics for all languages of the world, whereas I suspect that "Julius" is only for English pronunciation. CHEERS